# Visual Studio 2015 Ignores project specific includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl-2, glew, glm-math

I am attempting to create a fresh VC++ project in Visual Studio 2015, in which I will be using the following libraries:
SDL2
GLEW
GLM

As I have done many times before, I have set the project up as follows:

- Create empty project and add main.cpp with usual minimal main
  function and build.
- Add folder to solution directory (called lib), add copy the desired libraries to the folder.
- In project properties, under all configurations, I navigate to VC++ directories, and enter the path for each library under includes, and library directories.
- Under Linker>Input, I add the .lib files I will be using.
- Finally, I copy the .dll files into debug/release folders in the solution directory.

  At this stage, I should be able to type `#include <sdl2.h>`, or `#include <gl\glew.h>`, however, the headers cannot be found.

I have double checked all the filenames and paths, and all are correct. It's possible I may have missed something, but I've run through a few setup tutorials and checked a few old projects and everything seems fine.

Has anyone else heard of this, and if so, did you find a solution?

Comment: SDL on windows is `<SDL2/SDL.h>` and under *nix is `<SDL.h>`. I suggest using `"SDL.h"`.

Comment: When setting SDL's include directory, did uou set it to `SDL/`? or `SDL/include`? or `SDL/include/SDL2/`?

Comment: The setting was $(SolutionDir)lib\SDL2-2.0.3\include

Comment: That should be correct.

Comment: What error are you getting? Undefined reference? Undeclared reference? Or simply SDL.h not found?

Comment: That's what I thought, but visual studio refuses to recognise it. I thought It might just be an intellisense error, but, it throws a compiler error when I build with the #include statement. It's saying the file "SDL.h" can't be found, despite it being in the specified include folder

Comment: Could you double-check the VC-Directories setting? I remember having the same issue. It deleted what I typed. Is the directory you added still there?

Comment: I'm in the process of applying update 3 to visual studio, so once that's done, I'll do that and get back to you.

Comment: I've double checked all the settings in VC++ directories, and linker>input, and they're all correct.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I had to reinstall visual studio. I had previously installed 2017 before 2015, so installed them in chronological order. I don't know that if that made a difference, but everything works fine now.